# Game Center Leaderboard score upload failed in iOS 7.0

Tags: ios7

I've much googling because I've issue in implementing Game Center Leaderboard in iOS 7.. So I've got one important thing that is likely for solving the issue. From iOS 7.0, we should use identifier instead of category because category is deprecated from iOS 7.0.. I could get this fact from here. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW13

So I used identifier ... but it still faces with same issue... Score upload fails..

Belows are my code for reporting score.

```
GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier: identifier];
scoreReporter.value = score;
scoreReporter.context = 0;
scoreReporter.shouldSetDefaultLeaderboard = YES;
NSArray *scores = @[scoreReporter];

[GKScore reportScores:scores withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    //Do something interesting here.
    [self callDelegateOnMainThread: @selector(scoreReported:) withArg: NULL error: error];
}];
```

When reports score, it shows error and error is "The requested operations could not be completed because one or more parameters are invalid."

Any solution for it? I've been almost devoting 2 days for it but not getting anything funny.. Could anyone give me a solution? Need any helps .. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by removing the line

```
scoreReporter.shouldSetDefaultLeaderboard = YES;
```

:) Hope this helps other developers who are facing with the same issue as I was...